# How to get the original name of the image into an array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Hello guys I tried to upload two images but when I `dd`  the $filename I only got one name in the array

```
$data =  $this->validate([
            'image.*' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max
        ]);

if(!empty($this->image)){

$filename = [];

foreach ($this->image as $img) {

    $filename =  $img->storeAs('public/images', 'image_' . time() . $img->getClientOriginalName());                        
    
    
}

$data['image'] = $filename;

dd($filename); 

}
```

coz when I `dd` the data in my create it only pass one name

```
if($this->galleryId){
    Gallery::find($this->galleryId)->update($data);
    $action = 'edit';
}else{
    dd($data);
    Gallery::create($data);
    $action = 'store';
}
```

This the data on my `dd`

```
"public/images/image_1628844415Facebook-0064.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Chenge this line

```
$filename =  $img->storeAs('public/images', 'image_' . time() . $img->getClientOriginalName());
```

to

```
$filename[] =  $img->storeAs('public/images', 'image_' . time() . $img->getClientOriginalName());
```